# Why am I getting a hyphen at start of file?

Tags: c, file-io

I am learning C and I have tried to build a program that outputs its own source. This is my source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int S = 512;

int main(){
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("hello.c","r");
    char * line = (char *) malloc(S);
    int i = 0;
    while (i == 0)
    {
        i = feof(fp);
        printf("%s",line);
        fgets(line,S,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I have used the tcc compiler and I got this output:
[image: code outputs source correctly but adds a hyphen at the start]

But notice, I got a hyphen before `#include`. The rest of the output is correct.

So please can someone explain why I got this hyphen??

Comment: Are you sure that's not a byte order mark?

Comment: @HotLicks How can I check what it is?

Comment: Open the file with a hex editor.

Comment: @HotLicks The bytes in hex are 0xffffffc4

Comment: OK, as Ooga suggests, you are printing "garbage" that happens to be in the buffer before you read anything.  C does not "protect" you from this -- it's "undefined behavior" and you can get anything from apparently flawless operation to going down in smoke and flames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're printing the first line before you've read anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("hello.c", "r");
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
        printf("%s",line);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It solved the problem. But still, why did it print the hyphen and not something else? Why didn't it produce any error?

Comment: @Kartik It just printed whatever happened to be in the memory that `line` uses. You're lucky it was just a hyphen!

Answer (score 1):

@ooga gave you the correct answer.

The *why* is that malloc doesn't initialize the memory before it returns it to you, unlike its sister calloc.

Most likely, on another platform / compiler, you'd get something different.

Some compilers use a debug heap that initializes "unitialized" memory to a specific value. The release mode will probably result in random garbage instead of a '-' everytime.